# Passing string as parameter in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

Lots of people seem to be having problems with passing parameters with ajax. I looked at many of those posts but none of the answers worked for me.

I am working in Symfony. I am trying to pass parameters by ajax so that i can update the table data, but even though javascript reads my data, i can't seem to be able to receive it in my controller.

The Javascript function is :

```
$('#form-save').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var target = parent.attr('target');
    var title = $('#title-'+target);
    var id = $('#form-info').attr('row');
    var date = $('#date-'+target);
    var dateTime = new Date(date.text());
    var curr_date = ("0" + dateTime.getDate()).slice(-2);;
    var curr_month = ("0" + (dateTime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var curr_year = dateTime.getFullYear();
    var from = $('#from-'+target);
    var till = $('#till-'+target);
    var description = $('#description-'+target);
    //First Log
    console.log(target + title.text() + date.text() + from.text() + till.text() +description.text() );

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ path('restaurant_my_events') }}",
        data: {
            action: 'update',
            id: id,
            title: title.text(),
            date: curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date ,
            from: from.text(),
            till: till.text(),
            description: description.text()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            //Second Log
            console.log( response );

        }
    });
```

For debugging i am logging twice on the console, the output from the first log is :

```
0 hello world   06-14-2014  12:0612:06 description 2
```

This confirms that all the input elements are matched, there are no errors in reading the data, the output from the second log is just to verify that my parameters were received by my controller.

Controller Function is :

```
public function myEventsAction(Request $request){
    $restoID = 2;
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('LesDataBundle:Party');
    $events = $repository->findByRestoId( $restoID );

    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        $status = false;
        $action = $request->get('action');
        $partyID = $request->get('id');
        if($action == 'delete'){
               //Delete function
        }else if($action == 'update'){
                //Update function
        }

        $test = $action ." + ". $partyID ." + ". $request->get('title') ." + " . $request->get('date') ." + " .
            $request->get('from') ." + " . $request->get('till') ." + " . $request->get('description');

        return new JsonResponse(array(
            'id' => $partyID , 'request' => $request , 'test' => $test));
    }


    return $this->render("LesRestaurantBundle:Admin:Events/myEvents.html.twig",
                array( 'events' => $events ));
}
```

And the output from the second logging is :

```
Object {id: "2", request: Object, test: "update + 2 +  + NaN-aN-aN +  +  + "}
```

I only received the parameter id. Why?

Comment: Are you doing something in a pre-request callback (something that might be removing elements from the DOM)? What POST params are sent to the server according to the Network tab in your browser's developer toolbar? What are the values of curr_date/curr_month/curr_date when the first log line is written?

Comment: @juanrpozo No the information is static on the page, To send this information a popup formulaire opens up which takes the data from the same sources to pre-populate it's fields (works fine), and then i send the values from the input fields via Ajax. 
From the network logs, 
**Form Data:
action:update
id:2
title:
date:NaN-aN-aN
from:
till:
description:**

Comment: You are not responding to a hidden.bs.modal event either, are you? It seems that by the time the $.ajax call is triggered, the #title, #from, #till and #description elements are empty. What happens if you define the data object before hiding the modal, or if you hide the modal after calling the $.ajax method?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your strings with `encodeURIComponent()` before sending via AJAX.